# How to get nested key value from a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following structure:

```
{
  "$schema": "http:",
  "title": "al",
  "description": "An enitity ",
  "id": "a.json#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "symbol",
    "symbolText",
    "gene",
    "taxonId",
    "primaryId"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "primaryId": {
      "$ref": "..",
      "description": "The"
    },
    "symbol": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The symbol of the entity."
    },
    "symbolText": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "the "
    },
    "taxonId": {
      "$ref": "../g",
      "description": "The "
    },
    "synonyms": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "secondaryIds": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "."
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "gene": {
      "$ref": "../globalId.json#/properties/globalId",
      "description": "The "
    },
    "crossReferences": {
      "description": "Collection",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "../crossReference.json#"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
}
```

which is saved in a file called "my_keywordfile". 
and I want to have something like:

```
$schema.http,
type.object,
...,
**properties.primaryId.$ref,
properties.primaryId.description**
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
json_load = json.load(my_keywordfile)    
for key, value in json_load.items():
    # print((key,value))
    if type(value) == type({}) or type(value) == type([]):
        for x in value:
            for i in range(0, len(value) > i):
                 print(key+'.'+value)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? it works fine till this line:

```
for key, value in json_load.items():
        print((key,value))
```

This section, prints out keys and their values at the first level.
But it seems there is something wrong with the rest of the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_dotted_form(val, old=""):
    lines = []
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for k in val.keys():
            lines += get_dotted_form(val[k], old + "." + str(k))
    elif isinstance(val, list):
        for i,k in enumerate(val):
            lines += get_dotted_form(k, old + "." + str(i))
    else:   
        lines += ["{}.{}".format(old,str(val))]

    return [line.lstrip('.') for line in lines]

dotted_list = get_dotted_form(json_data)
dotted_string = ',\n'.join(s)
print (dotted_string)
```

**Output**

```
$schema.http:,
title.al,
description.An enitity ,
id.a.json#,
type.object,
required.0.symbol,
required.1.symbolText,
required.2.gene,
required.3.taxonId,
required.4.primaryId,
additionalProperties.False,
properties.primaryId.$ref...,
properties.primaryId.description.The,
properties.symbol.type.string,
properties.symbol.description.The symbol of the entity.,
properties.symbolText.type.string,
properties.symbolText.description.the ,
properties.taxonId.$ref.../g,
properties.taxonId.description.The ,
properties.synonyms.type.array,
properties.synonyms.items.type.string,
properties.synonyms.uniqueItems.True,
properties.secondaryIds.type.array,
properties.secondaryIds.items.$ref..,
properties.secondaryIds.uniqueItems.True,
properties.gene.$ref.../globalId.json#/properties/globalId,
properties.gene.description.The ,
properties.crossReferences.description.Collection,
properties.crossReferences.type.array,
properties.crossReferences.items.$ref.../crossReference.json#,
properties.crossReferences.uniqueItems.True
```

Comment: thx. Can you please tell me what does this line mean?  lines += get_dotted_form(val[k], old + "." + str(k))     @Sunitha

Comment: Also, this line please:           for i,k in enumerate(val):  lines += get_dotted_form(k, old + "." + str(i))   @Sunitha

Comment: In `lines += get_dotted_form(val[k], old + "." + str(k))` ,  we are recursively invoking  get_dotted_form for any nexted dicts. For eample consider we are parsing `properties` which is a dict. We are converting it to dotted form and adding the result back to `lines`. The new prefix we have to add for this dict is `old` (which would be `properties`) and adding current element to it. For example for the first element, the new prefix would be `properties.primaryId`

Comment: With `for i,k in enumerate(val): lines += get_dotted_form(k, old + "." + str(i))`, we apply similar logic for lists. They need to prefixed by the index, which would be obtained by enumerating it.  For example, consider the list `required`; each element has to be prefixed by the index 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: Thx, @Sunitha. What is the difference between val[k], and str(k). I understand that we are getting the keys of the json data, but why we then have str(k)?

Comment: `val` represents the nested dict we are processing. We loop through all keys in dict `val` and during that iteration, `k` represents the current key we are processing. So `val[k]` would be the value stored for the key `k` in the nested dict we are processing and `str[k]` would just be the key (just to be safer)

Answer (score 0):

You need this line to be printing `x` not `value` and you can remove the `for i in range(0, len(value) > i):`

```
for x in value:
    print(key+'.'+x)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. But do you know why it does not give me the nested nodes? Now it only give me ....  properties.secondaryIds          properties.gene       
properties.crossReferences     how can I have properties.genes.description?   @Michael Puckett II

Comment: @nina_dev You need to make the loop recursive.  Make it test if string then print and if another array then enter the test again.  It'll do this downward until it finds the inner most strings and prints them.

Answer (score 0):

The credit still goes to @Sunitha as I just modified the code to remove the last values, as well as, the index number in case the data is a list.

```
json_load = json.load(my_keywordfile)
def get_dotted_form(parent,values): 
lines = []
if isinstance(values,dict):
        for key in values.keys():
            # print(keys)
            lines+=get_dotted_form(parent+"."+key, values[key])
elif isinstance(values,list):
        for i,k in enumerate (values):
            # print(keys)
            lines+=get_dotted_form(parent+"."+k, values[i])
else:
        lines.append(parent)
return [line.lstrip('.') for line in lines]    

for x in get_dotted_form("",json_load):
    print(x)
    print('\n')
```